# What's the difference between Singleton and Registry design pattern

Tags: php, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I have some confusion between those two patterns:

**singleton**
Check if the instance exists return it, or create a new one.

**Registry**
Check if the instance exists return it, or create a new one and store it.

What the difference between them?

Comment: Registry implements the Singleton pattern.

Comment: @JohnConde no , it doesn't. Or at leas does not need to.

Comment: As far as I understand, a registry does not allow creating instances. The purpose is that the knowledge of how stuff should be created can be elsewhere, away from most clients of the registry. What you compare with seems to be a combination of a factory and a registry, largely defeating the purpose of a registry.

Comment: That's a trick question; the answer is `" and store it"` ;)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Both are about instance control. The difference is that Singleton allows only one instance of a given class while Registry holds a 1-1 map of keys to instances. Typically, the key is (or represents) a class and the value is an instance of that class.

For example, Code Igniter framework holds a registry with an instance of each library/model/controller/helper you load and returning those same instances every time.

Answer (score 7):

## Level of access and complexity

One fun filled caveat I always love, is that a registry pattern is utilizing a singleton to store/retrieve a dynamic list of objects.

### Singleton Pattern

Singleton pattern is a pattern by which you establish a single point of access and methodology.  While many people believe it is an anti-pattern, I assure you it is only because of the level they work at and type of programming they do.

Singleton patterns are used at lower levels to manage strict resources.  For instance, while most languages have libraries that wrap keyboard input, it is effectively a singleton pattern as it has very strict input/output and only one can exist, regardless of how many keyboards you have.

#### Testing Singleton patterns

One of the reasons people feel singleton patterns are anti-patterns, is they are in general untestable in a unit test system.  It is not possible to even mock a singleton in most languages, as it is fixed to a specific identity.

For this reason the singleton should be minimal, and a wrapper used to interface it.

You can then inject the wrapper and it can be mocked to used a fake singleton mock.

### Registry Pattern

The registry pattern is where you establish a single point of access, but not a single methodology.  This very registry access will have at least 3 methods: put, find, and delete.  These methods rely on a singleton pattern to work.

The map is testable, as it is not isolated to your use, and while the registry itself is not actually unit testable in connection to the units that consume it, you can utilize mocks of everything the registry is intended to contain.

However, if you utilize IoC in a given architecture consuming it, you can inject the registry from the container registry, allowing a mocked registry to be injected instead.

### Final note

Inversion of control is vastly popular these days, however big parts of it are often not learned or ignored. Some frameworks boil it down to mostly the factory pattern for most things, abstracting the rest away.

I would strongly encouraging most to toss out everything they know about IoC.

Then learn SOLID.
Afterwards read a book on design patterns for OOD. (Note: If the book has pros and cons of the patterns, it is good, if it does not show the cons, I would be very wary of the book.)

While these terms were coined relatively recently, the principles were learned in one manner or another early on, and in fact became the basis of Object Oriented Design.

The patterns most object oriented developers use successfully are all based on SOLID principles.

A reference to SOLID, that is laid out and summed up.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/conceptual_articles/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design

As a final suggestion:  Even if you are not an object oriented developer, it is very useful to learn SOLID and OOD, as must system architecture follows similar patterns when integrating a system together.

In addition I would not suggest you assume that one language/pattern/philosophy fits best for all needs.  Keep learning, keep an open mind. The more you know, the better the solutions you can bring to the table.

Answer (score 3):

A Registry differs in that its principal purpose is to allow you to navigate to associated objects. See [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/registry.html).

Answer (score 3):

The main difference between registry and singleton is that singleton allow us to create a single instance of a class at a time, whereas registry allows us to create multiple instance of the same class.

Comment: not much new compared to the accepted answer, is there ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Registry Definition: When you want to find an object you usually start with another object that has an association to it, and use the association to navigate to it. Thus, if you want to find all the orders for a customer, you start with the customer object and use a method on it to get the orders. However, in some cases you won't have an appropriate object to start with. You may know the customer's ID number but not have a reference. In this case you need some kind of lookup method - a finder - but the question remains: How do you get to the finder?

A Registry is essentially a global object, or at least it looks like one - even if it isn't as global as it may [appear](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/registry.html).

Singleton Definition: Sometimes it's important to have only one instance for a class. For example, in a system there should be only one window manager (or only a file system or only a print spooler). Usually singletons are used for centralized management of internal or external resources and they provide a global point of access to [themselves](http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html).

Based on these definitions their usage are completely different.